# Complex Numbers task

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I can't solve this set of equations, please help me.

$$(1+i)z_1 + (1-i)z_2 = 1+i$$
$$(1-i)z_1 + (1+i)z_2 = 1+3i$$

Comment: Please show what you have done.  It's exactly the same process as you would solve a system of equations with real numbers, except that you are computing with complex numbers instead of real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to multiply the top equation through by $(1-i)$ and the bottom one by $(1+i)$ to give

$$2z_1 - 2iz_2 = 2\qquad\qquad$$
$$2z_1 + 2iz_2 = -2+4i$$

You can now eliminate one of the unknowns and find the other.  You can then substitute this back and get the complete solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have one more problem. I know answers of this task and I've checked them, but i can't get same answer. Please take a look on this image

http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1319473344-clip-11kb.png

Comment: You have $4z_1=4i$ so $z_1=i$.  So $2i-2iz_2=2$, i.e. (dividing by $2i$ on both sides) $1-z_2=-i$, so $z_2=1+i$.

Comment: How do you get 4z1 = 4i ?

Comment: Added the two equations together.  More formally $2iz_2=2z_1-2$ and $2iz_2 = -2 +4i -2z_1$

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) and [Cramer's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

Comment: I'll have complex numbers test and I'm not allowed to use matrix :)

Comment: You don't have to use or mention matrices. Multiply first equation through by $1+i$, the second by $1-i$, subtract. This eliminates $z_2$, and you get a simple linear equation in $z_1$.

Comment: What @André suggests is [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), which does not require matrices.  It is one of the ways these problems were solved before matrices.

Comment: @Ruslan Slavenok. It is the way you used to solve two linear equations in two unknowns in early algebra. The only difference is that the numbers are non-real. You can also add the two equations, divide by $2$ to get an equation $z_1+z_2=$ and subtract the second equation from the first, divide by $2i$, to get $z_1-z_2=$. Then I think it will look very familiar. But the first way I described is more general.